# Stack Exchange Safari Notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications

This might be the wrong place to ask this, but was wondering if there was anyway to get any notifications come up on my Mac OS X desktop using the Safari notifications setting or something similar.

If not I was also wondering if there was any plans to bring this functionality to the website

Comment: What type of notifications? I thought there were desktop notifications (through chrome) for chat, though when I last looked, it was gone.

Comment: I was asking through Safari - You can register with a website to have notification updates sent straight to the notification centre (Safari Push Notifications) [Have a look here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/)

Comment: Just found a third party app called StackPop - Just trying it out [linky](http://stackapps.com/questions/4523/stackpop-stack-exchange-meets-os-x-notification-center)

Comment: Hasn't it been implemented yet?