# Notification about comments

Tags: support, notifications

How can I switch on notification in my profile when I have a comment or an answer on my question?

At this moment I have to monitor the site every 5-10 minutes to check if they are, and this is headache, because sometimes when I'm too busy and I can't reply on time.

How do I switch on and connect it to the Notification center on my Mac?

Comment: Unless there's an option to disable these notifications, that you accidentally turned on, you should be getting notifications in the top bar.

Comment: Or do you want emails? If so, you can enable inbox notification emails at https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

Comment: @Stijn ...I mean how to switch on and connect it to Notification center on my Mac.  
On the top of site I have notification, but I have to keep this page permanently open for monitoring

Comment: https://stackapps.com/search?q=mac+notification

Comment: How and where are they commenting to you?

Comment: There is no way to do this natively with Stack Overflow, but as @rene has already linked, you could look for a custom userscript to do it instead.

Comment: You should *really* update your question to include the part about Mac notifications ...

Comment: @DavidG... this is a pity

Comment: Maybe related, not a dupe I think: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268035/stack-exchange-safari-notifications and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260346/notify-on-desktop-using-html5-notifications-api

Comment: @rene ... I think that question had the same meaning, but since 2014 nothing changed

Comment: That is right, for things to change you have to wait for [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no built-in way to get notifications in the Mac notification center (or for that matter, Windows notifications) with Stack Overflow. You have two possible options:

1. As @rene has already [linked](https://stackapps.com/search?q=mac+notification) in the comments, you can use a custom userscript to do it instead.
2. Use the Android/iPhone app. The apps may not be the greatest experience, but they do push notifications out. So while you won't see them on your desktop machine, you will see them on your phone.

Comment: This is my only significant use of the android app.  I put my phone on the table.  When the notification arrives, the phone vibrates, and I can hear it.